# ImageButton doesn't overlap over the cardview, but a normal button // ImageButton no se sobrepone encima de cardview,pero un button normal lo hace

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am developing developing an app that at some point it will show some "study sheets". The problem is that for each item it should show two buttons that should overlap over the cardview, but it only works with a normal button when with an imagebutton it doesn't happen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/sheet_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sheet_text_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="SAMPLE OF CONTENT.SAMPLE OF CONTENT.SAMPLE OF CONTENT.SAMPLE OF CONTENT"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
                android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sheet_flip_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/sheet_card_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_flip_white_24dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sheet_show_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sheet_card_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: ScreenShoot of App]

Comment: I suspect that `elevation` is the answer. Normal `Button`s have elevation built in, but an `ImageButton` is not a `Button` so maybe it does not. Try adding `android:elevation="10dp"` to your ImageButton tags.

Comment: Thank you, that solution fixed the problem I had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` has default elevation (actually, it has a [StateListAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator.html) that provides elevation when the button is enabled) under the Material theme, whereas `ImageButton` does not , so you have to add `elevation` by yourself .

Answer (score -1):

add elevation to your `ImageView`

your card elevation is `8dp`, add `10dp` elevation to your `ImageView`

```
    android:elevation="10dp"
```

Now your `ImageView` will overlap `CardView`